# Formatting html form

Tags: html, css

I am trying to render a html form like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fHI7.jpg

The problem I am facing are:

1. I am not able to make the fields go in next line after the label
2. I haven't been able to get the firld length of first and last combined to be as long as that of the email (or password)

Any help is much appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
<form>
<label for="Name"><strong> Your Name:</strong></label>
<input type="text" id="Name_First" name="Name_First" required>
<input type="text" id="Name_Last" name="Name_Last" required>   

<label for="Email">Email Address:<input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" vrequired></label>

<label for="RegPassword">Password:<input type="password" id="RegPasswordRegPassword" name="RegPassword" required></label>
<form>
```

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/d6a4h9o8/

Comment: Why you are not using div instead of labels as you want the functionality of block element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your HTML is wrong, so no solution will work if you don't fix it first. So let's start with that:

```
<form>
<div class="row">
    <label for="Name"><strong> Your Name:</strong></label>
    <input type="text" id="Name_First" name="Name_First" />
    <input type="text" id="Name_Last" name="Name_Last" />   
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="Email">Email Address:</label><input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" />
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
        <label for="RegPassword">Password:</label><input type="password" id="RegPasswordRegPassword" name="RegPassword"  />
    </div>
<form>
```

Now that we have proper markup and have added some divs to aid with styling (pay attention to those `class="row"` divs) we can apply CSS this way:

```
form {
    background:#ccc;
    padding:30px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50%
}
form label {
    display: block;
}
input {
    width:300px;
}
.row {
    width:300px;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin:5px auto
}
.row:first-child input {
    width:142px;
}
.row:first-child input:last-child {
    position:absolute;
    right:-5px;
    width:144px
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpftogv3/) to see the result

Now, there are **MANY** ways to do it, this is just one, but the most important part is to have your markup fixed, then styling it is really easy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example similar to the picture.

***HTML***

```
<form>
<label for="Name"><strong> Your Name:</strong></label>
<input type="text" id="Name_First" name="Name_First" required>
<input type="text" id="Name_Last" name="Name_Last" required>   

<label for="Email">Email Address:</label>
<input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" vrequired>

<label for="RegPassword">Password:</label><input type="password" id="RegPassword" name="RegPassword" required>
<form>
```

***CSS.***

```
form{
    max-width: 500px;
    background: #d4d4d4;
    padding: 20px;
}

form label {display: block;}
input{padding: 7px 0;font-size: 25px;}
input[type="text"]{width:48.2%;}
input[type="email"],input[type="password"]{width: 98%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
label {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

You'll still have to do additional styling, of course.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#Name_First {
   ...
}
```

to target specific element with your css styles. 
and try read through http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/applyingcss/

what you want to focus on should be "display" and "width"